# How can use Node module to get idle time from an electron app?

Tags: node.js, electron

I want to use Node module to get idle time on my electron app,
for example use this module :
[node-system-idle-time](https://github.com/paulcbetts/node-system-idle-time) 
how can integrate this model with main.js electron file to read an idle time from the main window?
Please help me.

Comment: What do you mean integrating the module ? What **exactly** do you need ? Have you already installed it with `npm`, for example ?

Comment: I want to use nodejs module with my electron app to get an idle time for mouse and keyboard ( read the time in my app not in the terminal) for example :  mainWindow.once('ready-to-show',function(){
       // run node module here and read the result in the main window
       mainWindow.show(); 
   });

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use **Node System Idle Time** with your electron app , do the following steps:

1. Install node with this command:

   `npm install --save @paulcbetts/system-idle-time`

   Or if you are using [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/en/), then run:

   `yarn add @paulcbetts/system-idle-time`
2. Usage, In your Node JS application import it as:

   `var systemIdleTime = require('@paulcbetts/system-idle-time');`

   Then you can use it calling: `systemIdleTime.getIdleTime();`

   The method `getIdleTime` will return the system idle time in milliseconds.
3. Usage in Electron , If you are building an Electron application you need to 
    re-build the addon using Electron's version of Node.js. 
    you can use [electron-builder](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder) to build your app.

   `npm install --save-dev electron-rebuild`

   And then re-build the addon with:

   `./node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild`

Answer (score 2):

This is how I figured it out from [Electron Power monitor API's](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/power-monitor)

```
const {powerMonitor} = require('electron'); 
const idle = powerMonitor.getSystemIdleTime() // it returns in seconds when I am writing this
console.log('Current System Idle Time - ', idle);
```